# How can I determine the expected cost to win a game that has a 1/100 chance of winning?

Tags: probability

If a game has a 1/100 chance of winning, and the cost to play is $1.00. What is the expected cost to win the game?

Initially, I thought the answer was ${$1.00 \over 1/100}$. But this isn't really matching up with empirical data. I believe the inaccuracy is because a player stops playing after they win, and that that estimate doesn't take that into consideration.

Comment: As you can see you have a geometric distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Note the mean of a geometric distribution is $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ is the probability of winning a game, while its variance is $\frac{1-p}{p^2} \approx \frac{1}{p^2}$ for small $p$.

Comment: Each player stops playing a game after they win *or* lose.  They may then choose whether or not to spend *another* $\$1.00$ for the same chance at another prize.  Doesn't matter; you're after the cost to win expectation of a *game*, not of a player.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to determine the prize that makes the game fair, you are correct.  Before playing the player has $1$.  After playing s/he has $\frac 1{100}$ times the prize.  To make this equal, the prize should be $100$.  Most times the game is not fair, so the prize will be smaller.  What empirical data are you using?  Whether the player changes behavior on winning is not important.  Each game is independent, so if somebody doesn't play it doesn't matter.